# How to set conditional breakpoin based on parameter value using windbg

Tags: windbg, conditional-breakpoint

I want to set a conditional breakpoint based on a member of one parameter, 
Now I can use command dt to check this parameter, 
My code looks like this:

```
void test(const MyClassB &inst, int value)
{
}
```

Now I can use the dt command to view the first parameter, the result:

```
0:000:x86> dt MyClassB @esp+4
dbgee!MyClassB
   +0x000 id               : (null) 
   +0x004 m                : 0n2130567168
   +0x008 myClassA         : MyClassA
```

Now I want to set a conditional breakpoint on this method based on the value of inst.m, anybody can show me how to do that? Thanks a bunch!

And It's appreciated if anybody can give some information about how to use the offset(such as +0x004 for m), thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snippet Compiled with `cl /Zi /nologo /W4 /analyze %1% /link /RELEASE`  in msvc++2010exp

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    class MyClass {
        int width,length;
    public:
        void set_val(int,int);
        int  area(); 
    };
    void MyClass::set_val(int x , int y) {
        width  = x;
        length = y;
    }
    int MyClass::area() {
        return width*length;
    }
    void main(void) {  
        MyClass foo;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            foo.set_val(i,5);
            printf("%d\n",foo.area());
        }
    }
```

In windbg to set a conditional breakpoint on set_val() to **break when width == 7**

**Conditional Breakpoint syntax Explanation**

`classtest!MyClass::set_val`  `<module!class::method>`
`@@c++()` using `c++ expression evaluator`
`@ecx` holds the `this pointer` suitably type casted to `MyClass *`
`width` is a `member of MyClass`
we use `6` for comparison purpose in this demo
as we are setting `break point prior to execution of set_val()` method
(notice the `uninitialized garbage` when printing the `first time`
`gc` go from condition after displaying MyClass `if width != 7`
`.else is implied` to break when `width == 7`

**command should be in one line**

```
bp classtest!MyClass::set_val    
".if( @@c++((((MyClass *) @ecx )->width)) != 6 ) {dt MyClass @ecx ; gc }"
```

results

```
0:000> bp classtest!MyClass::set_val ".if( @@c++((((MyClass *) @ecx )->width)) != 6 ) {dt MyClass @ecx ; gc }"
0:000> bl
 0 e 00401000     0001 (0001)  0:**** classtest!MyClass::set_val ".if( @@c++((((MyClass *) @ecx )->width)) != 6 ) {dt MyClass @ecx ; gc }"
0:000> g
ModLoad: 5cb70000 5cb96000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ShimEng.dll
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n4205541
   +0x004 length           : 0n4208683
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n0
   +0x004 length           : 0n5
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n1
   +0x004 length           : 0n5
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n2
   +0x004 length           : 0n5
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n3
   +0x004 length           : 0n5
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n4
   +0x004 length           : 0n5
classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n5
   +0x004 length           : 0n5
eax=00000007 ebx=7ffdf000 ecx=0013ff70 edx=00416680 esi=00000000 edi=0098f6ee
eip=00401000 esp=0013ff60 ebp=0013ff78 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac po cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000293
classtest!MyClass::set_val:
00401000 55              push    ebp
0:000> dd esp l3
0013ff60  0040106c 00000007 00000005
0:000> x @eip
0:000> ?? @eip
unsigned int 0x401000
0:000> lsa . 0,1
>    8: void MyClass::set_val(int x , int y) {
0:000> dv
           this = 0xfffffffe
              x = 0n7
              y = 0n5
```

Comment: BTW, could you explain what're the values **0x000**, **0x004** used for, and HOW TO use them? Thanks in advance!
 `classtest!MyClass
   +0x000 width            : 0n0
   +0x004 length           : 0n5`

Comment: those are offsets to members width is defined as an int = 32bits in 32 bit machine so 4 bytes is the size of width width starts at 0x0 length follows it at + 4 and so on assuming you located a structure at say 0x403000  403000 will hold the width 403004 will hold length and so on

Comment: Thank you! Can we use these offsets based on the register, take your code for example, `ecx`? Maybe some code like `dd whatfunc(@ecx)+offset`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use pykd extension for windbg ( [pykd.codeplex.com](http://pykd.codeplex.com). It is easy to create condition breakpoint with it.

1. 0.2.0.29 ( recommended version )

   kd>!pycmd
   dbgee = module("dbgee")
   bp = setBp( dbgee.test, lambda bpId: getParams()[0].m == 2130567168)
   quit()
   kd>g
2. 0.3.0.10 ( developper version )

You can place code in  a file and run it with command:
!py --global  bp.py

0.2.x version can also runs scripts, but it runs it in a isolated environment and after exit all objects ( including breakpoints ) would be destroyed. So 0.3.x version has possibility to run a script in "global" environment ( all global objects live until pykd is loaded )

Comment: Thanks! BTW, do you know to use the offset to view the value by d command? Such as dd (somfunc(@esp+4) + offset), etc, I don't know...